# Pythagorean Triplet using Java8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I am trying to find all pythagorean triplets below a given number using Java8.

I tried to solve the problem with the code shown below. But, I am still mutating the triplets list.

I would want to know ways in which the below code can be implemented without mutating the list.

```
public static List<Triplet> returnPythogoreanTriplets(int num) {
    List<Triplet> triplets = new ArrayList();
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num).forEach(hyp->{
        IntStream.range(1, hyp)
          .forEach(side1->{
              IntStream.rangeClosed(1, side1)
                .forEach(side2->{
                    Triplet t = new Triplet<>(side2, side1, hyp);
                    if(t.isPythagorean()){
                        triplets.add(t);
                        System.out.println(t);
                    }
                });
          });
       });
    return triplets;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do that

```
public static List<Triplet> returnPythogoreanTriplets(int num) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num).boxed().flatMap(hyp -> 
        IntStream.range(1, hyp).boxed().flatMap(side1 -> 
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, side1).mapToObj(side2 -> new Triplet(side2, side1, hyp))
        )
    )
    .filter(Triplet::isPythagorean)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The trick is to [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) on each `IntStream` and turn them into a `Stream<Triplet>`. Unfortunately, since there are no `flatMapToObj` for converting an `IntStream` into a `Stream<T>`, we need to call `boxed()` to turn it into a `Stream<Integer>` before.

Sample code (with an appropriate `toString()` on the class `Triplet`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(returnPythogoreanTriplets(3));
    // prints "[Triplet [a=1, b=1, c=2], Triplet [a=1, b=1, c=3], Triplet [a=1, b=2, c=3], Triplet [a=2, b=2, c=3]]"
}
```

As a side-note, this is very slow brute-force implementation to build the pythagorean triplets :).

Answer (score 0):

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).boxed().flatMap(a ->
        IntStream.rangeClosed(a, 100) .filter(b -> Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b) % 1 == 0) .mapToObj(b -> new int[]{a, b, (int)Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)}) ).forEach(a->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));

Comment: Code is always good but it also helps to add some comments/context around how this addresses the original question.